# Scapy variable sniff stop

Tags: python, scapy, sniffing

i found a similar problem:
    ([Instance variables not being updated Python when using Multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412345/instance-variables-not-being-updated-python-when-using-multiprocessing)),
    but still do not know the solutionn for my task.

The task is to stop a scapy sniff function after the completness of a testskript. the running duration of single testscripts can vary greatly (from some seconds till hours). My sniff function runs in a separate threat. The testscript calls an init Funktion in the beginning which calls the sniff Function from an other modul.

```
@classmethod
    def SaveFullTrafficPcap(self, TestCase, Termination):
        try:
            Full_Traffic = []
            PktList = []
            FullPcapName = Settings['GeneralSettings']['ResultsPath']+TestCase.TestCaseName +"Full_Traffic_PCAP.pcap"
            #while Term.Termination < 1:             
            Full_Traffic = sniff(lfilter=None, iface=str(Settings['GeneralSettings']['EthInterface']), store=True, prn = lambda x: Full_Traffic.append(x), count=0, timeout=Term.Termination)
            print(Full_Traffic)   
            wrpcap(FullPcapName, Full_Traffic)
        except(Exception):
            SYS.ABS_print("No full traffic PCAP file wirtten!\n")
```

At the end of the testscript an exit function is called. In the exit function I set Term.Termination parameter to 1 and wait for 5 sec, but it doesnt work. The sniff function is stoped by the system and i get no file"FullPCAPName"
If count or timeout get a value, the code works without problemms and i get my FullPCAPName file with he complet traffic on my Interface.

Have anybody hinds how i can stopt the sniff function regulary after finisching the testscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of the stop_filter command as specified [here](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/989#issuecomment-352422415) worked for me. I've duplicated [HenningCash's](https://github.com/HenningCash) code below for convenience:

```
import time, threading
from scapy.all import sniff
e = threading.Event()
def _sniff(e):
    a = sniff(filter="tcp port 80", stop_filter=lambda p: e.is_set())
    print("Stopped after %i packets" % len(a))

print("Start capturing thread")
t = threading.Thread(target=_sniff, args=(e,))
t.start()

time.sleep(3)
print("Try to shutdown capturing...")
e.set()

# This will run until you send a HTTP request somewhere
# There is no way to exit clean if no package is received
while True:
    t.join(2)
    if t.is_alive():
        print("Thread is still running...")
    else:
        break

print("Shutdown complete!")
```

However, you still have to wait for a final packet to be sniffed, which might not be ideal in your scenario.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I modified my code, that i am using the thread as modul("StoppableThread") now, it also works fine. Your suggest should work, but i dont like to generate additional packets in my usecase.

Answer (score 0):

now i solved the problem with global variables. It is not nice, but it works well.

Nevertheless I am interested in a better solution for the variable sniff stop.

Answer (score 0):

```
stop_var = ""
def stop():
    global stop_var
    stop_var.stop()



def start():
    """
    your code
    """
    global stop_var
    stop_var = AsyncSniffer(**arg)
    stop_var=start()
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: @Shree's point is always true, but it's _especially_ important here, where there's already an accepted answer from a few years ago that's been validated by the community. Under what circumstances might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of new syntax that wasn't available when the original answer was written? Explaining not only your code, but why you took a different approach from the accepted answer can be really useful to future readers.