# Class instance's member not updated

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class with member variables `self._duration` that I am updating periodically by calling one of its method in a process. The class definition is as below :

```
class Tracker :

    def __init__(self):
        self._duration = 0
        
    
    def UpdateDuration(self):
        self._duration += 1
        print ("updated the duration to : {0}".format(self._duration))
    
    def GetDuration(self):
        return self._duration 
  
    def ThreadRunner(self) :
        while True :
            self.UpdateDuration()
            time.sleep(1)
```

I create an instance of the class in another file and start the process as below

```
trip = False 
end = False

while not trip :
    start = input("do you want to start the trip? : ")
    if start.lower() == "start" :
        trip = True


if trip :
    vt = Tracker()
    t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = vt.ThreadRunner, args=())
    t1.start()


    inp = input("Enter any char if you want to end the trip : ")

    t1.terminate()
    
    print ("Trip duration : {0}".format(vt.GetDuration()))
```

My issue is that while every time the `UpdateDuration` method is called, i get a statement saying that duration has been updated to the expected value. But when finally the trip is ended the `GetDuration` method returns 0, despite the fact that it is getting updated every second.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Instance variables not being updated Python when using Multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412345/instance-variables-not-being-updated-python-when-using-multiprocessing)

Comment: Your `while not end:` method is only performed once - so the most your value could be is 1 - that is supposed to be so?

Comment: no, the while not end part waits for my keyboard input, when I enter stop only  then the while loop exits after making the variable end = False. PS : I also added code to start the process, which I had missed earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work using the concept of Values in Multiprocessing library. Here is the code which gives me what I need :

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Lock

class Tracker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.duration = Value('i', 0)
    
    def UpdateDuration(self, val, lock):
        
        while True :
            time.sleep(0.01)
            with lock :
                val.value += 1

    def GetDuration(self):
        return self.duration
```

Then the calling script needs to initialize this class and its variable before creating the process :

```
    t = Tracker()
    t.counter = Value('i', 0)
    lock = Lock()
    proc = Process(target=t.Updater, args=(t.counter,lock))
    
    proc.start()

    inp = input("end the process : ")
    
    if inp == "y" :    
        proc.terminate()

    print (t.counter.value)
```

This solves my problem and updates the value of the duration as per the expectation.

Answer (score 0):

actually you are not starting your process `t1.start()` & in `ThreadRunner` you are using `while True` which mean will run continually.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the code to start the process (only on Stackoverflow!, it's there in my actual code) and won't the terminate method end the process?